# How to safely sanitize a textarea which takes full HTML input

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, sanitization

I'm developing a plugin which enables the user to send HTML emails from within the WordPress admin. How should I sanitize the textarea input? It has to be able to contain the whole range of HTML tags that might appear in an HTML email. If I use `wp_kses()` then I would have to use a huge list of allowed tags.

The textarea saves its content to the db via custom options.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is already [a huge list built for you](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/kses.php#L56), which can be returned by `wp_kses_allowed_html()` based on context, and filtered via the `wp_kses_allowed_html` filter, also contextually. Creating that list should not be hard.

However, "the whole range of HTML tags that might appear in an HTML email" should be pretty close to the range allowed for an ordinary post so [`wp_kses_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses_post) ought to get you a long way with little effort.

Comment: Yes that is a big list. So I just import that as the parameter  then add the extras I need, like `<html>` and `<body>` etc.

Comment: Yes,  if you need your users to include _that much_ markup. I'd generate that part for them, if it were me.